# Is there any meaning to the passing days?

Tags: the-witcher-3

I love to roam the open world of Witcher, and can't help noticing lots of game time is passing away while doing so. Day and night, over and over.

So far I did not notice any possible influence it might have on quests (neither the main quest, nor any side quest) however I have a feeling I might miss (or already missed) some things available only if I act quickly and finish things in a certain time range.

Can anyone tell for sure if there is any meaning, or side effects, to the passing days?

Comment: This question is deeper than it seems.

Comment: @GeorgeD well, didn't mean it to be deeper, lol.

Answer (score 22):

For the most part no, however some quests will require you to be present in a given location at/around a certain time of day/night.  And you can't, for instance, hunt nightwraiths at high noon (or noonwraiths at midnight), and most villagers will sleep during the night and work during the day, and so on.

And of course, if you go to sleep for 16 hours when you're supposed to be protecting the burial detail from necrophages there will be consequences (such as failing the quest because, you know, everyone got eaten while you were having your nap).  You can fail some active quests by taking too long, going to sleep, or otherwise wandering off when important things are happening.  But those situations tend to be obvious, and are the exception rather than the rule.

But in terms of whether or not the passage of entire days/weeks/months makes a difference?  No.  Except your beard will get longer.

Comment: Beard?? *Mental note: check Geralt's beard more often* ;-)

Comment: Yes, it was actually a [fairly](http://www.polygon.com/2015/3/24/8282437/the-witcher-3-geralt-dynamic-beard-growth-over-time) [big](http://www.theverge.com/2015/5/12/8586427/the-witcher-3-beard-growth) [deal](http://www.gamespot.com/articles/dynamic-beard-growth-confirmed-for-witcher-3/1100-6426116/) in the pre-release advertising/reporting.  Every game _needs_ dynamic beard growth.

Comment: Also there are situations like with Hattori where you can "recover" from doing something else, probably mostly for important quests/questlines.

Comment: There's also one quest that (depending on what you chose) you have to wait a few days before collecting payment.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, there are no sideeffects. Sometimes, you even have to wait because a quest is only available at a specific daytime or after a couple of hours or some monsters only spawn at a given time.

However, the only problem I've seen was that a quest failed. I've encountered a random merchant with his cart who asked me to burn the corpses around him. Somehow, i forgot that, went away and waited because I needed new potions. The quest failed after that, but this was the only drawback I had because of that.

Comment: Interesting about the merchant, so there might be some consequences. So far I failed only one stage of a quest, it was stage requiring me to talk with someone to find a certain location, and I failed because I found the location myself, by chance, while roaming the world. Not related to time though.

Answer (score 1):

There is a quest now in the Add-On "Hearts of Stone", where you only have a limited time.

Careful Spoiler:

> [Whatsoever a man soweth](http://www.ign.com/wikis/the-witcher-3-wild-hunt/Whatsoever_a_Man_Soweth)